# Number of trees variable in weka

Tags: java, weka, random-forest

In the current weka's implementation for random forest what is the variable that indicates the number of trees? They are using different naming for variables than Breiman?

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setNumTrees(int)` `getNumTrees()` and `m_numTrees` pre [weka 3.7.12](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.12/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.java#RandomForest.setNumTrees%28int%29)

`setNumIterations(int)` in [weka 3.8](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html) it was renamed, apparently in an effort to implement a RandomForest using the `Bagging` classifier with `RandomTree` as underlying implementation.

I'm going by the fact that both use the `-I` tag.

Also I checked, for `-I = 100` and `-I = 10` they have the same output for some random sample data.

[image: screenshot confirmng that -I is num_trees]

Comment: `-I <num>
  Number of iterations.
  (current value 100)` right?

Comment: I checked. It is. See screenshot.